# How do I get the country codes from polygons in my "grid data" polygon dataframe?

Tags: shapefile, r, overlay

I am relatively new to working with spatial data in R. 
I have two spatial polygon data frames. 
The first one is a shapefile which has a [grid structure](https://grid.prio.org/#/extensions) of a resolution of 0.5*0.5 for the whole world. 
The second one is a shapefile which has the [boundaries for Africa](http://www.maplibrary.org/library/stacks/Africa/index.htm) as the polygons including the state names . 
Both have latitude-longitude coordinates.

I would like to overlay the two files and drop every cell that is not in the Africa file, thus I would like to have only the cells that belong to Africa. 
In a second step I would then like to assign each grid cell the country it belongs to. 
Does anyone have an idea how I would do that? 
`intersect()` or `over()` didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you show your code that used "intersect" and "over"? It might have been very close to working and it gives us a starting point. Try and show code and plots whenever possible, and also summaries of your data (the output of `summary(things)` is usually a good start). This helps us help you!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past with a little bit of jiggery-pokery.

So the PRIO-GRID structure can be matched with country codes, but you have to download them first from their [website](https://grid.prio.org/#/download). 
I saved them as `priogrid.csv` in the code below.

In addition, they use a coding scheme no one uses except for the incidental political scientist.
Hence they need to be matched with a more common coding scheme like ISO. 
For this I used the `cshapes` and `countrycode` package.

Here's my shot at this: maybe not the cleanest way but it works (for what I need though). 
I am sure there might be some directer way to match the cells with the country codes but I haven't found out how yet.
I guess you can adapt it to suit your needs. 
Specifically matching it with your shape file for national boundaries.

```
#libraries
library(countrycode)
library(data.table)
library(rgdal)
library(cshapes)

#get GW code for African countries
poly <- cshp(date=as.Date("2014-12-31"), useGW=TRUE) #load map
poly$continent <- countrycode(poly$ISONAME,
                              "country.name", "continent", warn = TRUE) 
gw <- as.vector(na.omit(poly$GWCODE[poly$continent == "Africa"])) #GW country code

#get GID for African countries
gid.gw <- fread("priogrid.csv") #NB: this needs to be downloaded
gid <- gid.gw$gid[gid.gw$gwno %in% gw]

#subset priogrid to cells in Africa
grid <- readOGR(dsn = "priogrid_cellshp", layer = "priogrid_cell")
grid <- grid[grid$gid %in% gid,]

#add country code
intermediate <- data.table(gwno = poly$GWCODE, iso = poly$ISO1AL3)
gid.gw <- merge(gid.gw, intermediate, all.x=TRUE)
grid <- merge(grid, gid.gw, all.x = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking an sf route, you can use sf::st_intersection to intersect your grid and retain attributes.

```
library(sf)
library(raster)

CUB <- sf::st_cast(sf::st_as_sf(raster::getData('GADM', 
                   country='CUB', level=2)), "POLYGON")
  g <- sf::st_make_grid(CUB, 0.5)

plot(sf::st_geometry(g))
  plot(sf::st_geometry(CUB), add=TRUE)
```

[image: CUB grid]

```
cub.grid <- sf::st_intersection(CUB, g)
  plot(sf::st_geometry(cub.grid))
```

[image: intersect grid]